# Unique Session ID's for individual pages

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies, sessionid

I have unique session variables being set at different pages. I want to make my session variables discreet and localized in its respective page. The problem is that php stores a session id as a cookie for each user so that sessions are only unique to a user and not to pages.

How do I restrict sessions on a page to page setup?

Comment: i dont think its a good idea !

Comment: Why should you have _volatile_ and user-unrelated page info? Just persist them on db / code.

Comment: Because I want to identify certain pages to my php code. I chosen sessions as a means to allow pages to say "hey I am page such and such here is some data to use just for me".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be better off using a SINGLE session ID, and storing each of your page's localized data in a sub-section of the session, e.g.

```
$_SESSION['pages']['index.html'] = ...
$_SESSION['pages']['sitemap.html'] = ...
```

It is better to have just a single session floating around, rather than multiple ones. Unless your site is very small, you run the risk of exceeding the browser's per-site cookie limit, and you'll start losing sessions as the browser deletes 'old' cookies to make space for 'new' ones.